# Есть ли аналог VB.Net метода Strings.Format в C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, форматирование, format

Имеется старый код на VB.Net, который портируется на C#. В процессе возникла проблема с портированием [Strings.Format](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.format?view=netframework-4.8).
В коде используются
[именованные форматы даты времени](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.format?view=netframework-4.8#predefined-datetime-formats),
[именованные числовые форматы](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications#named-numeric-formats) и
[определяемые пользователем строковые форматы](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications#user-defined-string-formats)
*(так и не понял, почему на странице документации по Strings.Format не доступна вся информация об именованных форматах)*.

Проблема заключается в том, что вышеуказанные форматы сохраняются в двоичных конфигурационных файлах для которых необходимо обеспечить обратную совместимость. К примеру, имеется такой VB метод:

```vb
Public Function StringConvert(ByVal sValue As String, ByVal sFormatString As String) As String

    Dim RetWert As String
    Dim neuWert As String = Trim(sValue)
    Dim format As String = Trim(sFormatString)

    If format = "String" Then
        RetWert = neuWert
    ElseIf format = "General Date" Or
      format = "Long Date" Or
      format = "Short Date" Or
      format = "Medium Date" Or
      format = "Long Time" Or
      format = "Medium Time" Or
      format = "Short Time" Then
        If IsDate(sValue) Then
            RetWert = Format(CDate(neuWert), format)
        Else
            RetWert = ""
        End If
    ElseIf format = "General Number" Or
      format = "Currency" Or
      format = "Fixed" Or
      format = "Standard" Or
      format = "Percent" Or
      format = "Scientific" Then
        If IsNumeric(sValue) Then
            RetWert = Format(CDbl(neuWert), format)
        Else
            RetWert = ""
        End If
    ElseIf format = "Yes/No" Or
      format = "True/False" Or
      format = "On/Off" Then
        If IsNumeric(sValue) Then
            RetWert = Format(CBool(neuWert), format)
        Else
            RetWert = ""
        End If
    Else
        If InStr(format, "@") > 0 Or
           InStr(format, "&") > 0 Or
           InStr(format, "<") > 0 Or
           InStr(format, ">") > 0 Or
           InStr(format, "!") > 0 Then
            RetWert = Format(neuWert, format)
        ElseIf InStr(format, "c") > 0 Or InStr(format, "y") > 0 Or
               InStr(format, "d") > 0 Or InStr(format, "h") > 0 Or
               InStr(format, "w") > 0 Or InStr(format, "s") > 0 Or
               InStr(format, "m") > 0 Or InStr(format, "t") > 0 Or
               InStr(format, "q") > 0 Or InStr(format, "+") > 0 Then
            If IsNumeric(sValue) Then
                RetWert = Format(CDate(neuWert), format)
            Else
                RetWert = ""
            End If
        ElseIf InStr(format, " ") > 0 Or InStr(format, "%") > 0 Or
               InStr(format, "0") > 0 Or InStr(format, "-") > 0 Or
               InStr(format, "#") > 0 Or InStr(format, "E") > 0 Or
               InStr(format, ".") > 0 Or InStr(format, "e") > 0 Or
               InStr(format, ",") > 0 Or InStr(format, "+") > 0 Then
            If IsNumeric(sValue) Then
                RetWert = Format(CDbl(neuWert), format)
            Else
                RetWert = ""
            End If
        Else
            RetWert = CStr(neuWert)
        End If
    End If

    StringConvert = RetWert

End Function
```

Пробовал создать свой [IFormatProvider](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.iformatprovider?view=netframework-4.8) для форматирования DateTime, но он просто преобразует символы строковых форматов дат *(в примере ниже это `h` и `t`)*. Конечно можно импортировать пространство имён Microsoft.VisualBasic и использовать метод далее, но (насколько я понимаю) этот подход не будет работать с .Net Core, что критично.

Имеется ли аналог Strins.Format в C#? Может быть есть какая-либо библиотека (.Net Standard)? Каким образом, по Вашему мнению, можно оптимально решить эту задачу?

"Поиграться" можно [здесь](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ktVB97).

```cs
public class VBDateTimeFormatProvider : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
    public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        return formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter)
            ? this : null;
    }

    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _map = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"General Date", "G"},
        {"Long Date", "D"},
        {"Short Date", "d"},
        {"Medium Date", "D"},
        {"Long Time", "T"},
        {"Medium Time", "T"},
        {"Short Time", "t"}
    };

    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        format = format.Trim();
        return _map.ContainsKey(format)
            ? DateTime.Parse(arg.ToString()).ToString(_map[format], CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
            : string.Empty;
    }
}
// var dt = new DateTime(2020, 1, 1).ToString();
// Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse(dt).ToString(format, new VBDateTimeFormatProvider()));
// выводит: "S12orA DaAe"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VB.NET использует тот же .NET, что и C#. Так что берёшь проект на C#, идешь в references и добавляешь библиотеку `Microsoft.VisualBasic`. После чего используешь сколько хочешь.

Кстати, по [твоей же ссылке](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.format?view=netframework-4.8) написано:

> #### Применяется к
>
> **.NET Core** 3.1, 3.0
>
> **.NET Framework** 4.8, 4.7.2, 4.7.1, 4.7, 4.6.2, 4.6.1, 4.6, 4.5.2, 4.5.1, 4.5, 4.0, 3.5, 3.0, 2.0, 1.1

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что для использования с .Net Core будет достаточно установить NuGet пакет Microsoft.VisualBasic?

Comment: Не знаю, возможно. Но мне кажется, тот метод отправлял всё в winapi, так что я не уверен в его работоспособности в линуксе.

Comment: Получилось? А в линуксе работает?

Comment: Добавил ссылку на Microsoft.VisualBasic и записал в тех.долг. Не хотелось конечно использовать этот костыль, но из-за проблем с именованными форматами оставил пока так. Будет на Linux работать или нет не могу пока сказать, т.к. сейчас идёт первая фаза и до Linux'a ой как далеко...